# Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) in Cumulative Link Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, ordinal-data

A simple summary in R of a cumulative link mixed model (CLMM) provides the AIC value - does anyone know how to find the BIC of CLMMs though? There is not a method listed anywhere in the Ordinal package documentation. I'd like to be able to report both.

Comment: Which language are you using? Wiki'ing BIC will get you the definition as well as some properties. If you're asking about how to find it in a package you're probably in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AIC it is trivial to compute the BIC. AIC is just -2LL + 2k where k is the number of parameters and LL is the loglikelihood, and the BIC is -2LL + log(n)k, where n is the sample size.